# body scroll on d3 zoom and drag behavior

Tags: css, google-chrome, d3.js, svg, scroll

I'm working on a `d3` project like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) example. Everything are working correctly except when I start dragging shapes. As I'm dragging the shape which is placed in to the `SVG` container when mouse pointer goes beyond the `SVG` boundaries suddenly the scroll of the body works. Just in Google Chrome (latest version) the problem happens but in other browsers it's working correctly. In order to prevent this behavior I've done a hack and it is setting the `overflow` property of the body tag to hidden but it's not a suitable solution. is the any solution to stop body scroll when mouse pointer goes beyond the `SVG` boundaries?

Comment: I have the same problem, but the interesting thing is Google maps handled this issue. Although it uses also a SVG container, it handled this strange problem.

Comment: Maybe possible to use clipPath with rect element instead of overflow hack.

Comment: @FrancisHemsher The clipping path restricts the region to which paint can be applied. Actually I want drag behavior works out side the the boundaries with no effecting on the body scroll.

Comment: OK, I see. I don't think its possible to drag an svg element beyond root SVG.

Comment: @FrancisHemsher It's strange but it's working on the above example, because of the `d3 zoom behavio`r or `drag behavior`. You can check it out. The question is it's effecting on body tag too and starting window scroll and it happen just in Chrome browser.